# Reading data in-between symbols from Serial Arduino C

Tags: c++, c, arduino

How can I find the data in between the { } symbols and store the information in a char?

I have tried the following with no joy it keeps stopping.

```
void loop(){
      data = Serial.read();
      if(data>0){
        recData[i] = data;
        i++;
        Serial.print(data);
      }
    }
```

This is the code that reads the information.

```
void loop(){
  data = Serial.read();
  if(data>0){
    Serial.print(data);
  }
}
```

OUTPUT DATA:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain
Expires: Sat, 01 Feb 2014 22:06:18 GMT
Connection: close

{Read Data Inside Here}
CLOSED
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String finaldata = "";
void loop()
{

    while (Serial.available()) {
        char recv = Serial.read();
        if (recv != 0x00) finaldata += recv;
        if(finaldata.indexOf('}') > 1){
            int firstBracket = finaldata.indexOf('{');
            int secondBracket = finaldata.indexOf('}');
            finaldata = finaldata.substring(firstBracket, secondBracket);
            Serial.print(finaldata);
            break;
        }
        delay (10);
    }
}
```

Comment: GettingWebData:86: error: request for member 'substring' in 'data', which is of non-class type 'char'

Comment: @Gully, Serial.read() only reads a single char, you need to store it in a String variable to process it later

Comment: When i traid the code above it didnt work so i moved String finaldata = ""; out off the loop and it sorts off works some funny char are comming up {hÿeÿllÿoÿ wÿorÿlÿd

Comment: Yes and nothing was out putting so i moved the String finaldata = ""; out off the loop and now i am getting ÿ outputting in finaldata